# Renaming Excel sheets: name exceeds 31 characters error

Tags: excel, vba

The following renames all the worksheets in a single workbook.

I get this error:

[image: Error]

I think it's due to the exceeded character count limit. I have about 300 worksheets so I want to make an `If` statement so that if the `LEN` of the name is greater then 31, then it only names the file with the first 30 characters and leaves the rest.
Also, if there are characters like `/,\,?,*[,]` it should replace those with nothing.

```vb
Sub RenameSheet()
Dim rs As Worksheet
For Each rs In Sheets
  rs.Name = rs.Range("B2")
Next rs
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Replace()` to remove unwanted characters, and `Left()` to get the first 30 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be forbidden characters. You can try the following piece of code. It will first remove all those characters and then eventually cut the length of the sheet name to 30 characters.

```
Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    Dim sWorksheetName As String
    
    For Each rs In Sheets
        'Store desired worksheet name to a string variable
        sWorksheetName = rs.Range("B2")
        'Replace forbidden characters
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "/", "")
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "\", "")
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "?", "")
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "*", "")
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "[", "")
        sWorksheetName = Replace(sWorksheetName, "]", "")
        'If the desired name is longer then 30 characters, only the first 30 characters
        'are used as worksheet name
        If Len(sWorksheetName) > 30 Then
            sWorksheetName = Left(sWorksheetName, 30)
        End If
        
        'Rename the worksheet
        rs.Name = sWorksheetName
    Next rs
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Left function:

```
Sub RenameSheet()
   Dim rs As Worksheet
   For Each rs In Sheets
      Debug.Print rs.Range("B2")  'print file name before creating file
      rs.Name = Left(rs.Range("B2"), 30)  'first 30 chars only
   Next rs
End Sub
```

Comment: I added  `Debug.Print` in the answer. Give that a try. It should print the filename before trying to save it.

Comment: What was the last filename printed?